# zip any number of lists in a dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

**I am wondering if there is a way to zip multiple keys in a dictionary?**

For example:

I have a dictionary with time and uom.

```
Sample:
dict1 = [(time: '1','2','3','4','5'), (uom: 'kpa', 'mmhg', 'pds', '%', 'L')]
```

When I run again(or multiple times, since reading this from a file), I will have different keys in the dictionary, i.e (color, value, sport,...) and so on?

```
dict1 = [(value: '1','2','3','4','5'), (color: 'green', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange'), (sport: 'tennis', 'basketball', 'hockey', 'curling', 'baseball')]
```

The sizes for each key in the dictionary will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax of dicts wrong. Instead of writing:

```
dict1 = [(time: '1','2','3','4','5'), (uom: 'kpa', 'mmhg', 'pds', '%', 'L')]
```

You should write it as:

```
dict1 = {'time': ['1','2','3','4','5'], 'uom': ['kpa', 'mmhg', 'pds', '%', 'L']}
```

The process you described is called dict merging, and can be accomplished with the `update` method of dict. For example, run:

```
dict1.update({'sport': ['tennis', 'basketball', 'hockey', 'curling', 'baseball']}
```

And `dict1` will become:

```
{'time': ['1','2','3','4','5'], 'uom': ['kpa', 'mmhg', 'pds', '%', 'L'], 'sport': ['tennis', 'basketball', 'hockey', 'curling', 'baseball']}
```